# Writing a TeleOp-Node for a generic joystick

Tags: teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I' ve got an USB -Simulator RC-Transmitter that works very nice under Linux. Since I want to use it for my ROS-Robots I wanted to create a node as a driver.
The [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode) is really easy but running the command:

```
$ jstest /dev/input/js0
```

I get the following output from my TX:

[image: image description]

How should I interpret numbers like:

> Axes:  0:     0  1:     0  2: 20606

Means **20606** microseconds? Millivolts? Or something else?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191848/writing-a-teleop-node-for-a-generic-joystick/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok...I didn t find out what those number mean nor if they are milliseconds or millivolts or something like that.
Anyway: I modified this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode) and it works like a charm. Just take that number as it is and scale it to your needs.

Regards

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0